# React, how to update a component after an axios PUT request

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I'm trying to find a solution for my problem.
This is the situation:
I have an EducationComponent which contain the GET request (using axios) and then return a .map of all the education array, but the render of each item created by the .map is in another component, the EducationItemComponent, which contain a Collapse with a Form from which you can edit that item in the database, using a PUT request (made with axios).

Everything is working well, even if I am sure that I made a lot of chaos and surely it would be some easier ways for implement my App, but I am very new with React and JSX and this is the maximum I can do now.

What I'm trying to do is:
Once I have filled up the form and I have submitted it, and the PUT request has changed the data in my database, I would like to re-render the item and see imediatelly the changes I've done, but I cannot find any way for doing this.

Here is the code in the EducationComponent:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';

import { addEducation } from '../../redux/actions/educationActions';
import { EducationItem } from './EducationItemComponent';

export const Education = () => {

    const education = useSelector((state) => state.education.education);

    const { id, school, date, description } = education ?? {};

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const fetchEducation = async (id, school, date, descr) => {
        const response = await axios
            .get('http://localhost:3005/education')
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Err', err);
            });
        dispatch(addEducation(response.data));
        console.log(response.data[0].school);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchEducation();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="education clearfix">
            <h2 className="small-heading">EDUCATION</h2>
            <div className="education-container col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">

                { /* Education items */}
                {education.map(educ =>
                    <>
                        <EducationItem key={educ.id} id={educ.id} school={educ.school} descr={educ.description} date={educ.date} />
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And here is the code for the EducationItemComponent which render every component from the .map:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Collapse } from 'reactstrap';
import { ButtonGroup, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { faEdit, faTrashAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import axios from 'axios';

const putEducation = async (id, school, date, descr) => {

    var educUrl = 'http://localhost:3005/education/' + id;
    const newEducation = {
        id: id,
        school: school,
        date: date,
        description: descr
    }

    const response = await axios
        .put(educUrl, newEducation)
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Err', err);
        });
}

const submitEducationEdit = (event, id, success) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    putEducation(id, event.target.school.value, event.target.date.value, event.target.description.value);
}

export class EducationItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = { 
            open: false
        };
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="item" key={this.props.id}>
                    <div className="bullet hidden-xs">
                    </div>
                    <div className="education-content">
                        <h3>{this.props.school}<span> / {this.props.date}</span></h3>
                        <p>
                            {this.props.descr}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="edit">
                        <ButtonGroup vertical>
                            <Button onClick={this.toggle} variant="success"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} /></Button>
                            <Button variant="danger"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} /></Button>
                        </ButtonGroup>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.open}>
                    <Form onSubmit={(e) => submitEducationEdit(e, this.props.id, this.state.success)} id="educationEditFormId">
                        <Form.Row>
                            <Form.Group className={"half"}>
                                <Form.Label>School</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    name="school"
                                    as="textarea"
                                    rows={1} />
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group className={"half"}>
                                <Form.Label>Date</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    name="date"
                                    as="textarea"
                                    rows={1} />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form.Row>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                name="description"
                                as="textarea"
                                rows={5} />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button
                            variant="success"
                            type="submit"
                            size="sm" >
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </Collapse>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

I was also trying to write the putEducation and the fetchEducation consts in the educationReducer (I'm using Redux for manage my store), but I cannot use for example the useDispatch() hook because I cannot use it at the top level, and I cannot find a way for use it, and I don't know if I have another way to dispatch the response that I get from the axios GET request.
If I could write them in the educationReducer it would be maybe easier because I could maybe call them from both my components and then use the useEffect hook for refresh the item, or something like this.
I really don't know how to fix the problem and what is the best way.

Thank you in advance guys.

Here is how it looks my educationActions right now:

```
import * as ActionTypes from '../constants/ActionTypes';

export const addEducation = (education) => {
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.ADD_EDUCATION,
        payload: education
    };
};
```

And this is the educationReducer:

```
import * as ActionTypes from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = {
    education: [],
}

export const educationReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case ActionTypes.ADD_EDUCATION:
            return { ...state, education: payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does this action do `addEducation` ? can you add that code as well ?

Comment: Here, the problem is you are not updating the redux store after you put the data in DB and hence your data is not getting updated. For achieving the same, you can just call a dispatch inside `putEducation`  for updating a part of store and make sure you pass the dispatch instance too .

Comment: addEducation is doing nothing more than taking the data from the dispatch and loading them in the payload.

export const addEducation = (education) => {
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.ADD_EDUCATION,
        payload: education
    };
};

Comment: I can add the code in the post so it can be more clear.
I wasn't thinking on dispatching again from the putEducation request, I can try and see if it works.